# Right way to make deploy to production

Tags: git, symfony, deployment

[Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/faq.html#what-files-should-i-commit-to-git-and-which-should-i-ignore) says to keep /public/build folder in .gitignore

So when I'm pushing my files, there no build folder on production, so I need to build assets.

But documentation also says that assets need to build on the dev server.

So, I need your advice about the right way to deploy.

1) Push build folder with git?

2) Install yarn, nodeJs on production and deploy after git pull?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The second. The 1st one always seemed weird to me, I generally never want to push build files to git, the same way I don't push my vendor dir.

Other than the weirdness, you have dev and prod config for encore too, so you will have to pay attention to olny push prod compilations. (example: source maps)

Another problem is asset versioning (https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/versioning.html). Since the file names are changing, you will generate unnecessary elements to the change log. If you are working with a team, this might also generate git conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to do this. (Symfony recommends those.)

1-) You should have a build server. In addition, you could send builded files with scp or tools are which help to move files. (For big and complex projects.)

2-) You could build for production on your development machine and you are supposed to move builded files.

3-) You could install npm or yarn on production machine. But personaly it's unnecessary. This option is the last thing that recommended.

For now, i prefer second option. You are supposed to watch this video :)

https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/webpack-encore/production-build

Answer (score 0):

I will build files locally and deploy by Ansible. 
Thank you all.